# Snap.svg change attr on hover using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this, snap.svg

I'm drawing four rectangles on a Snap.svg canvas and want to change e.g. the opacity of the one the mouse cursor currently hovers over. I wanted one function to work for all those rects and thought there must be a way doing this using the keyword `this` but my code doesn't work and I don't understand why.

What am I doing wrong? This should be possible right?

```
var s = Snap(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);

var firstBox = s.rect(0, 0, 480, viewportHeight);
var secondBox = s.rect(480, 0, 480, viewportHeight);
var thirdBox = s.rect(960, 0, 480, viewportHeight);
var fourthBox = s.rect(1440, 0, 480, viewportHeight);

firstBox.attr({
    fill: "lightblue",
    id: "firstBox"
});

function hoverEffect() {
    this.attr({
    fill: "red"
    });
}

$(this).on("hover", hoverEffect);
```

Comment: I don't understand how **Snap** works, but from a javascript point of view, the variable `this` will have no such attribute as it's a simple object (the function itself). if you had it in the `"hover"`  call then `this` would be that function and doing `$(this)` you will get the object you need... in order that to work, you need to pass the variable, something like: `$(this).on("hover", hoverEffect(this));` and then use that variable in your function.

Comment: @balexandre Ok, I'm not sure I did it right but I get the error: 'this.attr is not a function'. Does that simply mean that I cannot change objects using this.attr in snap?

Comment: I did explain why and how you should go around that...

Comment: $(this), what is this in this context ? You could probably do it all in Snap , something like Snap.selectAll('rect').forEach( function() { this.hover( hoverEffect ) } ). You may even be able to do Snap.selectAll('rect').hover(hoverEffect) but I can't test from here.